# How to set defer .close correctly in golang with dependency injection

Tags: mysql, sql, go, dependency-injection

I want to set `defer xxx.Close()` to close connection in golang.
But if I set `defer xxx.Close()` after `INSERT` SQL method, its result is null.
If I remove `defer xxx.Close()` after `INSERT` SQL method, its result returns proper value.
I set `defer xxx.Close()` to avoid connection limit and crash. But now this is not avoided if I remove `defer xxx.Close()`.

- I set dependency injection in golang.

dao.go

```golang
package dao

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
)

type Dao struct {
    database *sql.DB
}

func NewDao(database *sql.DB) *Dao {
    objs := &Dao{database: database}
    return objs
}

type DaoInterface interface {
    GetEmployeeListDao() *sql.Rows
    RegisterEmployeeDao(employee model.RegisterEmployee, uu string, encrypted string)
}

func (d *Dao) GetEmployeeListDao() *sql.Rows {

    results, err := d.database.Query("SELECT id, name, email, isDisplay FROM employee")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    //it returns nothing.
    //If removing defer results.Close(), results returns correct value
    defer results.Close()
    return results
}

func (d *Dao) RegisterEmployeeDao(employee model.RegisterEmployee, uu string, encrypted string) {
    ins, err := d.database.Prepare("INSERT INTO employee(name, email, password, isDisplay) VALUES(?,?,?,?)")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //same problem will occure here.
    defer ins.Close()
    _, err = ins.Exec(uu, employee.NAME, employee.EMAIL, encrypted, employee.ISDISPLAY)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

service.go

```golang
package service

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "io"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Service struct {
    dao dao.DaoInterface
}

func NewService(dao dao.DaoInterface) *Service {
    return &Service{dao: dao}
}

type ServiceInterface interface {
    GetEmployeeListService() []model.Employee
    RegisterEmployeeService(c *gin.Context)
}

func (s Service) GetEmployeeListService() []model.Employee {
    var employee []model.Employee

    results := s.dao.GetEmployeeListDao()

    singleEmployee := model.Employee{}
    for results.Next() {
        err := results.Scan(&singleEmployee.ID, &singleEmployee.NAME, &singleEmployee.EMAIL, &singleEmployee.ISDISPLAY)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        } else {
            employee = append(employee, singleEmployee)
        }
    }

    defer results.Close()

    var displayEmployee []model.Employee

    for _, e := range employee {
        if e.ISDISPLAY == true {
            displayEmployee = append(displayEmployee, e)
        }
    }

    return displayEmployee
}

func (s Service) RegisterEmployeeService(c *gin.Context) {
    var employee model.RegisterEmployee
    c.BindJSON(&employee)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte("aes-secret-key-1"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    b := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(employee.PASSWORD))
    cipt := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(b))
    iv := cipt[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(cipt[aes.BlockSize:], []byte(b))
    encrypted := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(cipt)

    s.dao.RegisterEmployeeDao(employee, encrypted)
}
```

I set dependency injection style in api.
main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db := db.NewDatabase(os.Getenv("MYSQL_USER"), os.Getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"), os.Getenv("MYSQL_HOST"))
    dao := dao.NewDao(db.DATABASE)
    service := service.NewService(dao)
    cntlr := controller.NewController(service)
    router := handler.NewHandler(cntlr)

    router.Router.Run(":8080")
}
```

I expect `defer xxx.Close()` to has no problem and insert and select sql returns correct value.
But the problem is because of `defer xxx.Close()` insert and select sql does not return correct value.
I want to know how to avoid connection limit and crash without this problem.

Comment: You want `defer db.Close()` in `main`. Otherwise, you'd be attempting to close the "connection" after each request that uses the database. Something to note is that when you're opening a new database "connection", you are actually getting a pool of several connections.

Comment: You can't scan rows after you closed them. Have whatever code is scanning the rows close them instead. The comment reading "same problem will occure here" can't be correct, because you're not returning rows from that function.

Comment: @Gavin Thanks for advice!!. So You mean I need to set `defer db.Close()` at the end of line before `router.Router.Run(":8080")`?  Is it enough to prevent connection limit and crash for `insert` and `select` sql execution in `dao,go`?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for advice!! "You can't scan rows after you closed them" I got it! Thanks! So I need to close db connection at the end of main method, is it correct?

Comment: You're returning `*sql.Rows` from a function that contains a `defer .Close()` call on the return value... how do you expect that to work?

Comment: I got it. After taking sql values, I'm gonna close it.

Comment: To limit the number of connections use [DB.SetMaxOpenConns](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxOpenConns) and [DB.SetMaxIdleConns](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxIdleConns). Closing the DB at the end of main is pointless, because the program exits anyway when main ends.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for advice, I'm gonna use use `DB.SetMaxOpenConns` and `DB.SetMaxIdleConns` instead of `defer .Close()`.

Comment: Bye the way, is it meaningless to set `defer .Close()` after *sql.Rows values are taken in service.dao and after `ins.Exec` in dao.go?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're expecting is for the result set to be returned immediately as an array or something like that. This doesn't happen because the client is *lazy* - it doesn't give you results until you explicitly try to read a row using `Next()`. This is with good reason - if a result set has millions of rows in it, it'd be very slow to transmit the data over a network connection, and could even potentially exhaust the memory of the machine running the query. To avoid this, the result set is actually more of a "handle" that allows you to fetch more rows from the DB when you need them, rather than the results themselves.

When you call `Close()` on a result set, it signals that you no longer need any more data.

There might also be some confusion about `defer` here. `defer` triggers at the end of the function, so it will trigger when you return:

```
defer results.Close()
return results  // defer is triggered here, which will close the result set
```

Then when you try to read from it, it is a closed result set and so you can't actually read anything from it.

For reference, [here](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close) are the docs for what exactly happens when you call `Close()` on a result set.

Comment: very useful response. Thanks!